# xmr-stak-cpu compilation issue

Tags: 14.04, compiling

I'm trying to install xmr-stak-cpu on Ubuntu 14.04 following steps described in the installation TXT file: https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak-cpu/blob/master/LINUXCOMPILE.md

But unfortunately it fails at the end of `make install` and I'm completely lost and do not know in which direction to dig.
There is the full output of `make .` and `make install` following next link: https://pastebin.com/p76xkgpA

Could you please help me with any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Maybe you could check the "link.txt" file at xmr-stak-cpu-1.3.0-1.5.0/CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-cpu.dir/link.txt ; the symptom looks like linking by cc/gcc, not g++/c++; otherwise, you also need to check if your g++/c++ is symbolic linked to cc/gcc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have taken the liberty of simplifying the directions available
on the git site with the expectation that if you follow *these*
directions you will get a functioning executable under Trusty Tahr.

**1. Install the required compiler:**

The following is *a single command* which can simply be copied and then pasted into Terminal window:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test && \
sudo apt update -y && sudo apt-get install -y gcc-5 g++-5 make && \
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 1 \
--slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5
```

Bear in mind that the `update-alternatives` command is designed to automatically use *this version* of gcc for compiling. Test this version as follows:

```
andrew@ilium:~$ gcc --version | head -n 1
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~14.04) 5.4.1 20160904
andrew@ilium:~$
```

Bear in mind that the *default* version of gcc under Trusty is 4.8.2.

**2. Install the required version of cmake:**

The following is *a single command* which can simply be copied and then pasted into Terminal window:

```
mkdir $HOME/xmr-stak-cpu_build && cd $HOME/xmr-stak-cpu_build && \
wget http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.4/cmake-3.4.1.tar.gz && \
tar xvf cmake-3.4.1.tar.gz && cd cmake-3.4.1 && \
./configure && make && sudo make install && \
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cmake cmake /usr/local/bin/cmake 1 --force
```

Bear in mind that again the `update-alternatives` command is designed to automatically use this version of cmake for compiling. Test this version as follows:

```
andrew@ilium:~$ cmake --version | head -n 1
cmake version 3.4.1
andrew@ilium:~$
```

Bear in mind that the *default* Trusty version of cmake is actually 2.8.12.

**3. Download and build xmr-stak-cpu:**

The following is *a single command* which can simply be copied and then pasted into Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libmicrohttpd-dev libssl-dev libhwloc-dev && \
cd $HOME/xmr-stak-cpu_build && \
wget --content-disposition \
https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak-cpu/archive/v1.3.0-1.5.0.tar.gz && \
tar xvf xmr-stak-cpu-1.3.0-1.5.0.tar.gz && \
cd xmr-stak-cpu-1.3.0-1.5.0 && \
cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/xmr-stak-cpu && make install
```

The executable and config file will now be found in: `$HOME/xmr-stak-cpu/bin` 
and all that remains is for you to set up your config file! Seen on my own
14.04 system:

```
andrew@ilium:~$ cd xmr-stak-cpu/bin/
andrew@ilium:~/xmr-stak-cpu/bin$ ./xmr-stak-cpu -h
[2017-10-22 16:41:22] : Usage ./xmr-stak-cpu [CONFIG FILE]
andrew@ilium:~/xmr-stak-cpu/bin$
```

**Notes:**

- If all else fails I have created *a static build* of this application suitable for 64bit Trusty That can be installed as follows:

  ```
  cd $HOME && \
  wget http://www.andrews-corner.org/downloads/xmr-stak-cpu_64bit_static.tar.gz && \
  tar xvf xmr-stak-cpu_64bit_static.tar.gz
  ```

  This was created using the above technique but with the addition of the option `-DCMAKE_LINK_STATIC=ON` when compiling xmr-stak-cpu.
- [Compile xmr-stak for Linux](https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak-cpu/blob/master/LINUXCOMPILE.md): Directions for Linux compiles.
- If you like you can now completely remove the build folder:

  ```
  rm -rfv $HOME/xmr-stak-cpu_build
  ```

Comment: On the third step I got same error output like I copied to pastebin. gcc & cmake are installed and have same version as in your output.May it be that cmake compiling xmr-stak-cpu uses different version of gcc?

Comment: Seems odd, especially if your tested versions of cmake and gcc mirror mine. Do you have other compilers installed? My own installation was on a fresh VM of the latest Trusty version, my suspicions are that you have an older installation...

Comment: The versions are exact same as yours. I'm not sure about different versions of gcc. How can I check that?

Comment: `lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty`

Comment: I have created a pastebin of my successful compile: https://pastebin.com/qD7Jmw5H for others to peruse. My own Trusty is: `andrew@ilium:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty
andrew@ilium:~$ ` and I confess I am unsure why you cannot replicate my results :(

Comment: I has to be something with my system. I found a similar case https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/157 but do not have a clue what is the resolution.

Comment: Try the above method on a clean VM?

Comment: I'm sure it will work on the clean installation, but I need to do it on the current server

Comment: Hmmm... I cannot solve the riddle but perhaps you would be keen to test a static binary if I make it available for download? I presume you are using a 64bit installation...

Comment: I have placed directions for the static binary in my answer, hopefully this will at least get the application running on your system :)

Comment: Will try to do a static build on VM and then run it on the server. Thank you!

Comment: Static build is working

Comment: Finally success :)